# Why is this simple node.js code freezing?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, redis, express

Here's an extension of the sample node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var application = express.createServer();

var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

client.set("test key", "TEST KEY VALUE", redis.print);

application.get('/', function(request, response) {
        client.get('test key', function(err, value) {
            client.quit();
            response.send('The value of "test key" is: ' + value);
        });
});

application.listen(2455);
```

The server starts up fine, but when accessed, the page loads for a while eventually erroring out - "No data received."

I have redis running, the keys save fine, I can also access them via client.get() juts fine in node's repl.

I think I'm missing some theory on how async programs work.

Comment: Do you get the same behavior if you use `response.end` instead of `response.send`?

Comment: I'm not sure now, but I fixed the problem just now - shouldn't have quit the client inside the get(). Next time a request comes in, the client is disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think Redis/redis libraries require you to kill the client connection explicitly.  Even if you do, you need to ensure that the successful or error callbacks have been invoked & handled before quitting the client.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is possibility that you receive an error, and because you are not checking *err* variable before res.send, your application returns nothing. Try to add something like: 
`if(err) throw err;`
after client.get and check STDOUT